# SQL: Where this exists -> Compare two tables and check if they have the same number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, compare

I am at the end of my SQL knowledge. I have the problem that I want to check for existence whether two tables have the same number of rows.

An example could be that I want to show all schools where the number of chairs are the the same number of students. My pseudo Code looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM schools WHERE
  ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chairs));
```

or with a pseudo calculation: students - chairs = 0;

```
SELECT * FROM schools WHERE
  ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chairs) = 0);
```

Is such a construction with SQL possible and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems a little unorthodox, but you can do it with correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM schools s.
WHERE ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students st WHERE st.school_id = s.school_id) =
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chairs c WHERE c.school_id = s.school_id)
      );
```

I would be more inclined to do a join after aggregation:

```
select st.school_id
from (SELECT st.school_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM students st 
      GROUP BY st.school_id
     ) st JOIN
     (SELECT c.school_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM chairs c
      GROUP BY c.school_id
     ) c
     ON st.school_id = c.school_id AND st.cnt = c.cnt;
```

The two versions are subtly different.  This version will only return school ids that have at least one student (and chair).

EDIT:

I should note that if you just want to know if two tables have the same number of rows, you can return a boolean in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chairs c) =
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students st)
       ) as num_rows_same_flag
```

Because of the presence of the `schools` table, though, I assume you want the schools with the same numbers of each.

Comment: Hello Gordon, thanks for your answer, you helped me much to understand. To your last sentence: I only want to show the schools where the number of chairs and students are the same.

Comment: @Martin . . . That is what I expected.  However, the title to your question suggests that you are referring to the entire table (not just each school), so I added the edit.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I have now modified my code and it works like expected.